# Warning in system(cmd): 'make not found, Rtools Anaconda

Tags: r, anaconda, rtools

I try to install the latest version of rlang because i need it for scales and ggplot2. So I run:
`install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/rlang_1.0.2.tar.gz",repos=NULL,type="source")`

But I have the following  error message :

- installing *source* package 'rlang' ...
  ** package 'rlang' correctement décompressé et sommes MD5 vérifiées
  ** using staged installation
  ** libs
  Warning in system(cmd) : 'make' not found
  ERROR: compilation failed for package 'rlang'
- removing 'C:/Users/coich/anaconda3/envs/rstudio/lib/R/library/rlang'
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/coich/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpaw0zcr/downloaded_packages/rlang_1.0.2.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Then I saw that I have maybe to install the latest Rtools but I use Rstudio on Anaconda, so how I can do that.

Thank you for you aswer :)

Comment: Why are you trying to install it from source? Version 1.0.2 is available in CRAN. You should just be able to do `install.packages("rlang")`

Comment: Because when I do that I have a old version of rlang, even if remove rlang close Rstudio and retry. Thank you for your time

Comment: Do you get an error message when you run `install.packages("rlang")`? I don't understand how you can still have an old version of `rlang` if that command runs successfully. Installing from source won't be any different. Are you using an old version or R?

Comment: My problem is solve.I installed Rstudio without going through anaconda; then I downloaded all the libraries I needed one by one which worked well, and by miracle by going to Rstudio through anaconda my rlang became a rlang 1.0.2: what I wanted !!!!

Thanks for your answers